# setting context of input template to this using ng-template, ng-container & ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I have a costumizable component that uses an ng-container to ether show a default template or a passed in template.
The problem is I need the passed in template to have its context set to the component its nested in. I tried setting the **context** property on the **ngTemplateOutlet** directive to an object that holds **this** of the nesting component, however it did not work.

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<ng-template #didYouVisitQuestion>
    <div class="mt-10">
        <ds-radio-buttons
            ...
            (onSelectRadio)="alertx()"></ds-radio-buttons>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<nesting-component [questionTemplate]="didYouVisitQuestionTpl"></ds-rate-component>
```

**Parent Component Class/TS:**

```
@ViewChild('didYouVisitQuestion')
private didYouVisitQuestionTpl: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**Child Component HTML**

```
<ng-template #defaultQuestion>
    some default html...   
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="questionTemplate ? questionTemplate: defaultQuestion;context:cntxt">
</ng-container>
```

**Child Component Class/TS**

```
@Input()questionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
constructor() {
    this.cntxt = this;
}
alertx() {
    window.alert('alertx');
}
```

**The Problem:**

I need the **alertx()** method activated on the nesting component, currently it is activated on the parent component. passing the ngTemplateOutlet a context of **this** did not work.
How do I make the passed in template to have the right context in this situation?

Comment: can you please share stackblitz code

Answer (score 0):

Please find the Stackblitz code on passing scope.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpnguf